# Makefile using directory structure for source and object files - 2

Tags: makefile

First of all, Sorry I have reposted this question,
Since earlier post question was not upto the mark.. and i don't want to delete it since users have replied to the post

Here is my Folder Structure :

```
Project : Makefile, final.hex
|- Src : one.c two.c
|- Obj : one.o two.o
```

Here is my Makefile :

```
TARGET = final.hex
CC = gcc
SRCDIR = Src
OBJDIR = Obj

SRC = one.c two.c
OBJS = $(OBJDIR)/one.o $(OBJDIR)/two.o

CFLAGS = -c 
LFLAGS = -Wl

.PHONY: all

all: $(TARGET)

$(TARGET): $(OBJS)
        @echo ****** TARGET ********
    @echo Target.hex created


$(OBJS): %.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
    @echo ****** OBJS ********
    @echo $@
    @echo $<
```

When I tried to run makefile it gives an error :
make: *** No rule to make target `Src/Obj/one.c', needed by` Obj/one.o'.  Stop.

The question is there any method or another solution where we can tell makefile to look into $(SRCDIR) for *.c files for compilation even though *.o files to be remain in $(OBJDIR)

Note: I'm new to the world of Makefile & Stackoverflow

The question is there any method or another solution where we can tell makefile to look into $(SRCDIR) for *.c files for compilation even though *.o files to be remain in $(OBJDIR)

Note: I'm new to the world of Makefile & Stackoverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply have to look at the expansion of the variables and how they match the pattern.  Let's look at what your makefile says:

```
$(OBJS): %.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.c
```

This will expand to this:

```
Obj/one.o Obj/two.o: %.o: Src/%.c
```

When make matches `Obj/one.o` with `%.o`, the stem (`%`) will be `Obj/one` of course.

Then make will substitute that stem into `Src/%.c` so you get `Src/Obj/one.c`.  That is not what you want.

You want the stem (the part that matches the `%`) to be just the file name with no directory: `one`.  So, you have to write your rule to make that so.  Use:

```
$(OBJS): $(OBJDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.c
```

This expands to:

```
Obj/one.o Obj/two.o: Obj/%.o: Src/%.c
```

and now when make matches `Obj/one.o` with `Obj/%.o`, the stem matches just `one` and so the prerequisite will be `Src/one.c` which is what you want.